# Firebreath plugin not generating the package file after the compilation on Mac

Tags: firebreath

I created a plugin with Firebreath on Mac and after the code compilation it not generating the package(.pkg).

In windows using Wix tool kits, it generates the windows .msi but not with Mac OS.

I am using Xcode 4.6.2 and package maker installed in the Mac OSX version 10.7.5.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in .pkg installer in FireBreath